# Could not resolve host on cURL request PHP

Tags: php, curl, ubuntu-16.04

I'm starting to build my first API, after succesful testing on localhost(Mac OS X El Capitan) I uploaded it to my digitalocean server running Ubuntu 16.04.

I've both tried to run the cURL request from my localhost and from the server where the API is stored and both of them return "Could not resolve host" error with error number 6. My code:

On API side just

```
echo "200";exit;
```

On client side

```
$token = 'this is the session token';
$url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/API/index.php";
$data = array('username'=>'username','password'=>'password');
$datajson = json_encode($data);

$message = $url . $datajson . 'PUT';
$publishThis = base64_encode(
        hash_hmac('sha256', $message, 'secret key', true)
    );
    $len = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($message);
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',$len, 'Authorization: ' . $publishThis));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datajson);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    $response  = curl_exec($ch);
```

help please!!

P.S: if I remove the urlencode function the request takes for about 20 mins and ends on a 400 bad request error

Comment: No! Don't `urlencode()` the _whole_ url! You only encode special parts in the query part that would collide with the URL syntax.

Comment: Hmm ok, so the error i get now is 400 bad request, any clue plzz

Comment: That clearly is a reply from the receiving side. Obviously there is nothing we can say about how that API works and what requests it might expect. Sorry.

Comment: It might be that the `PUT` verb is causing issues. Are you sure that API can handle such requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LATER EDIT:

```
$token = 'this is the session token';
$url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/API/index.php";
$data = array('username'=>'username','password'=>'password');
$datajson = json_encode($data);
$build_query = http_build_query($data);

$message = $url . $datajson . 'PUT';
$publishThis = base64_encode(
        hash_hmac('sha256', $message, 'secret key', true)
);
$len = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($build_query);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',$len, 'Authorization: ' . $publishThis));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$build_query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);

if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}   

echo $response;
```

CHANGES:

`$build_query = http_build_query($data);`

`$len = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($build_query);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$build_query)`

remove url encode from `CURLOPT_URL`